# Replace specific pattern (shortening notations) by full notation in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of short forms like

Ann-e/i is the short form for Anne and Anni

How can I replace the pattern -e/i in the data frame by the full notations?
Another example is Matt-e/i for Matte and Matti.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What do you want for "Annerl,Ann-e/i"-- "Annerl, Anne and Anni"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have comma-separated values you can do either of this depending on your desired outcome:

Data:

```
string <- c("Annerl,Ann-e/i", "Matt-e/i")
```

First solution:

```
sub("(^\\w+)-(\\w)/(\\w)$", "\\1\\2 and \\1\\3", unlist(strsplit(string, ",")))
# [1] "Annerl"          "Anne and Anni"   "Matte and Matti"
```

Second:

```
c(sub("(^\\w+),(\\w+)-(\\w)/(\\w)$|", "\\1, \\2\\3 and \\2\\4", string[grepl(",", string)]),
  sub("(^\\w+)-(\\w)/(\\w)$", "\\1\\2 and \\1\\3", string[grep(",", string, invert = TRUE)]))
# [1] "Annerl, Anne and Anni" "Matte and Matti"
```

Comment: What do you mean by `incorrect`?

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! :) And what would it look like for words like An(n)a when I want both options: Anna and Ana? Sorry, I still try to wrap my head around it.

Comment: What do your strings look like? Can you give me an example withh all variants of Anna?

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c("Ann-e/i", "Matt-e/i")
gsub("(^[a-zA-Z]+?)-([a-z])/([a-z])$", "\\1\\2 and \\1\\3", x)
[1] "Anne and Anni"   "Matte and Matti"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works if there is no other word before the searched pattern. If I have a list like Annerl,Ann-e/i it does not work. Any idea how to adapt it?

Answer (score 1):

Wimpel's suggestion using `gsub` from base R works well and is quite flexible. Another approach is provided by the package [stringr](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html) from the tidyverse, which might be more intuitive.

```r
library(stringr)

strings <- c("Ann-e/i", "Annerl", "Matt-e/i")
str_replace(strings, "(\\w+)-e/i", "\\1i or \\1e")
#> [1] "Anni or Anne"   "Annerl"         "Matti or Matte"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You'll find it helpful to learn about regular expressions (regex), if you're not already familiar with them. Since there are several varieties of regex with different syntax, here's a link that is specific to using it with stringr. https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

Comment: You do not have to capture the second group. ie `(\\w+)-e/i`. This is a great answer. +1